# How to alter how a popup appears on OpenLayers Map

Tags: openlayers, wms, popup, html, css

I've the following JavaScript code for a popup to display on my OpenLayers map

```
// Create a popup overlay which will be used to display feature info
var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup();
map.addOverlay(popup);

// Add an event handler for the map "singleclick" event
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {


    // Hide existing popup and reset it's offset
    popup.hide();
    popup.setOffset([0, 0]);

    // Attempt to find a marker from the planningAppsLayer
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
    });

    if (feature) {

        var coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        var props = feature.getProperties();
        var info = "<h2><a href='" + props.caseurl + "'>" + props.casereference + "</a></h2>";
            info += "<p>" + props.locationtext + "</p>";
            info += "<p>Status: " + props.status + " " + props.statusdesc + "</p>";
        // Offset the popup so it points at the middle of the marker not the tip
        popup.setOffset([0, -22]);
        popup.show(coord, info);

    } else {

        var url = lakes_wms.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
                        evt.coordinate,
                        map.getView().getResolution(),
                        map.getView().getProjection(),
                        {
                            'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
                            'propertyName': 'namespace,Stat_2015'
                        }
                    );

        reqwest({
            url: url,
            type: 'json',
        }).then(function (data) {
            var feature = data.features[0];
            var props = feature.properties;
            var info = "<h2>" + props.namespace + "</h2><p>" + props.Stat_2015 + "</p>";
            popup.show(evt.coordinate, info);
        });
        
        var url = rivers_wms.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
                        evt.coordinate,
                        map.getView().getResolution(),
                        map.getView().getProjection(),
                        {
                            'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
                            'propertyName': 'namespace,Stat_2015'
                        }
                    );

        reqwest({
            url: url,
            type: 'json',
        }).then(function (data) {
            var feature = data.features[0];
            var props = feature.properties;
            var info = "<h2>" + props.namespace + "</h2><p>" + props.Stat_2015 + "</p>";
            popup.show(evt.coordinate, info);
        });

    }

});
```

The popup is currently appearing as below
[image]

I've tried adding styling to the HTML file for the popup but it has no effect. I would just like a white background and black border so that it looks more like a popup - nothing fancy, just readable.

I'd also like to be able to add Status: BEP to the popup rather than just BEP

Comment: You already had the same question with two people commenting and investing their time trying to help. You didn't respond to last comment, but rather deleted previous question and posted the same one again. You can hardly expect help with this kind of behavior.

Comment: Not the same question actually as I have since progressed

Comment: If the question you want answered has progressed/changed and it remains unanswered then please always edit to improve it rather than deleting and asking the next revision as a new question.

Comment: @PolyGeo Apologies, I didn't realise. I thought it best to ask a new question. I will know for future reference, thank you

Comment: I think of deleting as being the tool of last resort. Especially for anyone relatively new to the site because deletions feed into the algorithm that an automated process uses to issue post bans. As your rep increases that risk lowers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who may run into the same issue, I've found this works:

```
.ol-popup-content {
        background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230,0.7);
        color: black;
        border: 1;
      }
```

I had originally been calling it `popup` in html but it had to be the above in order to change the displaying properties

Comment: OpenLayers has no native popup functionality. Which OL 3-rd party library are you talking about?